# Is it possible to add a statement to python3 via an import? Or do I have to modify c files and recompile

Tags: python, python-3.x

In cPython >= 3.0, is it possible to add a statement to the language via an imported module?  Say I wanted to implement a case/switch statement, could I write that as a module, or would I have to edit cPython source files as per [PEP 306](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0306/) and recompile the language entire?

Comment: I used a case statement as an example, but what I would really like to do is see if I can re-implement the print statement in python3. I agree with the rational behind changing print from a statement to a method, and would not like to see the decision reversed.  But I would like to see an implementation of print for python3 for learning purposes.

Comment: It depends on what you want to learn.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your new language construct can be converted to standard Python: yes, technically it can be done using [import hooks](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/). Basically, you have to read the file, substitute valid Python for your language construct (a task which may well require a full parser), compile the generated Python source, and return a module object. Not for the faint of heart, but it's technically feasible.

Comment: Or, having a trace hook for every line of code executed: http://entrian.com/goto/ Also not a good idea. :-)

Comment: The `goto` trick is at least valid Python syntax to begin with though.

Comment: Well, it would be if goto was a keyword. :-) But there must be a way to make a switch statement that is equally "pythonic"? I haven't really thought about it.

Comment: `goto .label` is parsed the same as `goto.label` which is just regular attribute access on an object named `goto`. So it's valid Python to begin with. (Same with the `label` "statement"). The trick is, catching that and making it do what you want, which in this case can be done with trace hooks; I've also seen it done with bytecode hackery in a decorator.

Answer (score 3):

Use a ladder of if/elif's to do your switch.  Don't fight the language.  Learn what it does well, and do those things:

```
if x == 1:
    do_1()
elif x == 2:
    do_2()
elif x == 17:
    do_17()
else:
    something_else()
```

Adding statements is a major effort, and designing them well is even harder.  There have been discussions on the python-ideas mailing list about switch statements.  Read those to get a sense of the issues involved.

Answer (score 2):

Don't even try. You'd have to edit the source and recompile.

Instead, ask yourself why you NEED a switch statement, and realize that it's just not necessary.

```
def firstfunction(x):
    print(x)

def secondfunction(x):
    print(x + 15)

def thirdfunction(x):
    print(x / 15.0)

choices = {
    '5': firstfunction,
    5: secondfunction,
    30: thirdfunction,
}

if x in choices:
    choices[x](x)
else:
    print("default case")
```

Comment: Also, a `case/switch` is basically just a glorified `if/elif/else`. If your application is simple enough, then an `if/elif/else` should be fine.

Comment: Right, I'm not missing a switch statement. I *am* missing a "until" statement though. `while True` is a bit silly.

Comment: @LennartRegebro , why can't you do something like `while x < 5:` and then increment x in your block? (or `while some_list:` and just keep popping and adding to the list)

Comment: @JeffTratner: Uh, because if I did that I'd use a for loop? `while True` and `break` is the simplest and clearest way to do a `loop-until` in Python. And it's still silly.

Comment: @LennartRegebro haha okay, sure. the only real difference between the two is that a for loop requires you to peel off values on every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

No, statements cannot be added. You would have to find a workaround using functions, classes and/or object.

For the case of a switch/case: you could do it in several ways.

For example, with a mere dict:

```
def process(a):
    d = {3: lambda: func1(1, 2, 3),
         4: lambda: func2(3, 2, 1),
        }
    call = d.get(a, lambda: elsepart(a))
    return call(a)
```